# How to set Header for DataGridview RowHeader?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

Is there a way to put text into the the upper left header cell of a DataGridView?

The red x marks the spot I want to fill with text:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `grid.TopLeftHeaderCell.Value = "Text";`.